# Argument $map of map-get($map, $key) must be a map

Tags: css, sass

```
$width: (camera: 1842, tv: 2066, lamp: 1050, phone: 1173, full: 3521);
$height: (camera: 1149, tv: 1488, lamp: 1107, phone: 1196, full: 2484);
$size: map-get($width, full) / map-get($height, full); // no error

@function get-width($width) {
   @return #{$width * 100 / map-get($width, full)}vw; // error
}
```

This code give me error: argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Comment: Your function parameter `$width` is a `map` so you should not be multiplying it by 100 as you're doing in the `function body` - `$width * 100` that part of the code is invalid

Comment: @Black-Enigma Oh, i`m idiot. Thanks.